# What are the technological limitations of DNA computing?

Tags: computational-physics, physical-chemistry, biophysics, biology, computer

IBM and Microsoft are studying the application of [DNA computing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNA_computing), but I was wondering what are the technological limitations that prevent it from being used in the same way as a conventional digital computer? What are the challenges that need to be addressed in order to make it just as viable?

Comment: DNA computers (like quantum computers) are an area of active physics research - closely related to nanomachines/ratchets. Therefore I think it is a valid question.

Comment: @Vadim Being relevant to physics is only a necessary condition to be on topic; it is not a sufficient condition. In addition to the current close reason, this question is also somewhat subjective and fairly broad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DNA computing is essentially mechanical computing using macromolecules. The computers made in this way are slower and less scalable than the electronic chips:

- DNA self-assembly and other similar processes are essentially chemical reactions, much slower than switching electric current.
- DNA is a molecule that has the size bigger than the logical gates of modern computers.

DNA computers are not intended to be used instead of the econventional computers, their advantages are (e.g., in the domain of drug delivery) :

- they can be deployed in environments where the usual computers cannot be or even dangerous - e.g., computing protein consentrations in human blood or tissues and releasing the necessary amount of a medication/drug (conventional semiconductor materials can be toxic to human)
- they are easier to interface with organic materials than the semiconductor chips, which can do it only via additional hardware.